# Downlad a specific ubuntu package file

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I need to download ***sudo rm mysql-server-8.0_8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb*** file locally (not using command line). where can i download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official website [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com)

Precisely the link of what you are looking for is here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=510005. You have to click on "No thanks, just start my download" the download starts automatically. But the file is in tar.xz format.

Or for the `deb` format from unofficial web site https://pkgs.org/download/mysql-server-8.0